# Draw HTML5 Canvas with different background color than text?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, geometry

I am looking to draw a canvas circle with text, however I want the canvas background color to be different from the color of the text in the circle. my code below uses the same color for both background and text ..

```
<canvas id="circlecanvas" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("circlecanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
    context.arc(centerX, centerY, 25, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    context.fillStyle ="#dbbd7a";
    context.fill()
    context.font = 'bold 20pt Calibri';
    context.textAlign = 'center';
    context.fillText('34', centerX, centerY);
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
context.arc(centerX, centerY, 25, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
context.fillStyle ="#dbbd7a";
context.fill()
context.font = 'bold 20pt Calibri';
context.textAlign = 'center';

context.fillStyle ="#ff0000";  // <-- Text colour here
context.fillText('34', centerX, centerY);
```

So, basically, set the `context.fillStyle` for the text.

Comment: Wonderful - it works great. However, now that I can see the text, it it not centered in the circle! The textalign doesnt seem to be working. Looking to center the text element in the circle.

Comment: I am planning to populate the filltext area with a number ( which is changing dynamically).  Is that possible ( can I drop a number in there or is it just for text?) or should I be using another property to show the number on the canvas circle ? The number is for web pages - page 1 , 2, 3 , so looking to change the number in the circle as i page though the site.

Comment: @user2022284: You'll have to re-draw the contents of the canvas when pagin, and just replace the `'34'` in there with a number variable.
So, yea, that's very possible.

Answer (score 0):

as you asked in the comments, the solution for centering the text vertically
is adding this

```
context.textBaseline = 'middle';
```

to Cerbrus's answer